# Need a help in Inserting data of nested checkboxes into database as given in the below image.how to save days and it's timing in an array in php

Tags: php, mysql

`[image]

I need a help in submitting this data to the database.
Thanks in advance.
here is a HTML code,

```
       <div class="col-lg-4">
     <input type="checkbox" id="mont1"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mon" name="day[]" value="mon">Monday
     <div id="mon" class="collapse" style="margin-left: 16px;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="mont" />
       Morning :9am to 11am  <br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="mont1" />
       Afternoon :1pm to 3pm  <br>

    <input type="checkbox" id="mont2" />
       Evening :7pm to 10pm  
     </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: you should try to make array of checkbox.

Comment: put html code here for checkbox

Comment: There are many tutorials and examples of PHP and MySQL that can be found via Google to get you started.

Comment: One idea, which I like, is to store the weekday combinations bitwise so, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 4 = Wednesday, and 127 = everyday.

Comment: I am able to get days in an array but how to get respective timings

Comment: @Firdousbhat please edit your question and add your existing code, and we will help you. Comments are not the right place to add your code.

Answer (score 0):

One, economical way of storing the above is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(session TINYINT PRIMARY KEY
,day_of_week TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,119),(2,115),(3,0);
```

where day_of_week is a bitwise integer as follows:

```
 1=Monday
 2=Tuesday
 4=Wednesday
 8=Thursday
16=Friday
32=Saturday
64=Sunday

115 = Monday + Tuesday + Friday + Saturday + Sunday
```

Comment: i want to first make an array which will have selected days and their selected timings.

Comment: I need a help in making an array in PHP that contains the selected days along with there selected timings

Answer (score 0):

Guys atlast i was able to get the solution,

```
$days = array();
$times = array();
if (isset($_POST['day']))  $days = $_POST['day'];
foreach ($days as $day => $value) {
    # code...
    echo "$day => $value <br>";
    $times = $_POST[$value];
    foreach ($times as $time => $time_value) {
        # code...
        echo "$time_value <br>";
    }
}







    <div class="col-lg-4">
 <input type="checkbox" id="mont1"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mon" name="day[]" value="mon">Monday
 <div id="mon" class="collapse" style="margin-left: 16px;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="mont" name="mon[]" value="Morning :9am to 11am"/>
   Morning :9am to 11am  <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="mont1" name="mon[]" value="Afternoon :1pm to 3pm"/>
   Afternoon :1pm to 3pm  <br>

<input type="checkbox" id="mont2" name="mon[]" value="Evening :7pm to 10pm "/>
   Evening :7pm to 10pm  
 </div>
 </div>
```